# I would like to know if it's possible to push a React component into a JavaScript datatable?

Tags: reactjs, datatable

I would like to know if it's possible to push a React component into a JavaScript datatable, for example in my code below, I want my ShoppingList component to be rendered inside my ShoppingTable.

```
class ShoppingList extends React.Component {
confirm() {
    alert('Are you sure?');
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="shopping-list">
            <h1>Shopping List for {this.props.name}</h1>
            <ul>
                <li onCLick={this.confirm.bind(this)}>Instagram</li>
                <li onCLick={this.confirm.bind(this)}>WhatsApp</li>
                <li onCLick={this.confirm.bind(this)}>Oculus</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}}
```

second component :

```
class ShoppingTable extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() { 
    var data = [];
    data.push([
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
            <ShoppingList name={'firstname'}/>
        ])

   var dataTable = $("#" + this.props.itemId).DataTable({
        data: data,
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>ShoppingList</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    );
}}
```

Comment: While having an array of varying datatypes (strings vs React Components) is a bit unorthodox, there's no technical limitation for what you're to do. It should work.

Comment: @lux my datatable displays [object Object] instead of my component but, when I try ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<ShoppingList name={'firstname'}/>) my component shows up but the function confirm() does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The first option would be to render your table using react, if your code is as simple as in your example, it's the best solution. This is usually the best solution and easier to maintain in the long run than try to mix framework like react inside jquery and so on.

If it's not an option then I recommend creating a root react element for each react component that need to be included and create separate react contextes.

That way your data becomes something like that:

```
data.push([
   'firstname',
   'lastname',
   '<div class='component-ShoppingList' data-name='.firstname.'/>'
])
```

Then you need to detect when jquery's datatable redraw and create react contextes accordingly:

```
const rootElements = document.querySelectorAll('.component-ShoppingList')
rootElements.forEach((element) => {
    const name = element.dataset.name
    ReactDOM.render(
        <ShoppingList name={name} />,
        element
    );
}
```

Of course this code need to be adapted to create/recreate react elements when appropriate in relation to your datatable but you should get the global idea.

Comment: I need to use datatable because there is already predefined functions like pagination, deferRender etc... and in my case i have approximately 3000 lines in my table so your example does not fit I guess.

Comment: then take the second part of my answer, push a simple div selectable with a class, then, make react render it using ReactDom.render as provided in my example. Just put that code in the draw event of the datatable and you are good to go !